# Can I get the Process ID of a worker process in a web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, application-pool, worker-process

I have an application that runs in an application pool that has muliple worker processes.

I need to access the process id in the controller to check some issues I have since I changed the application pool to use multiple worker processes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This gets the process id

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id
```